# Binary classification penalizing only one class

Tags: binary-classification, cross-entropy

Let's suppose that the task is the following binary classification: Does this image have a cat or a dog? These are the four possible predictions:

1. It predicts cat and the image has cat.
2. It predicts cat and the image has dog.
3. It predicts dog and the image has cat.
4. It predicts dog and the image has dog.

If we only care about the first two and we want when it predicts cat the image to really have cat, totally ignoring the performance when it predicts dog, or at least at the beginning not caring about the missing cats when it predicts dog, how is this subset of binary classification problems called? In that case what is the binary loss entropy?

For example, in torch when the loss is defined, there should be the weight [1, 0]?

Something like that:

```
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=torch.Tensor([1,0]))
```

I would appreciate some general advice and guidance about this problem.

Comment: Why not just always predict a cat?

Comment: There will be much more images with dogs. I want it to detect all the ones with cats and at the beginning I don't care what happens when it predicts dogs. It matters the % of success when it predicts cat.

Comment: So why not always predict a cat?

Comment: Imagine 10 images with cats and 90 images with dogs. If it only predicts cat then the success would be 10%. If it only predicts dog the success would be 90% but I dont want this success. I want it to predict 10 cats, and finally 8 or 9 out of these 10 predictions would be cats.

Comment: Are you familiar with precision-recall curves?